# Facebook page tab above all in my page timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-tabs

I have a facebook page with a tab and I am wondering how can I achieve something like the picture below:

[image]

How the pink colored section can be added (not in the page menu tab but the first box of the timeline which is above everything).

I am also wondering how can this possibly be added to the mobile as well like the following picture?

[image]

Comment: This isn't possible. Shop tab is a custom tab provided by Facebook and Shopify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the `Shopify` documentation, and hasn't this type of integration.

https://docs.shopify.com/manual/more/facebook

[as @phwd says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35260577/facebook-page-tab-above-all-in-my-page-timeline#comment-58437983), it's not possible.